# Check whether a class is a member of a package

Tags: python, class, error-handling, package, mysql-connector

I am using the mysql.connector module. If an error is thrown as a result of `connection.commit()`, i.e. the "do the operation" command, how do I find out whether the class of that error is a member of its "package of classes" (if this is the right word)?

So I have:

```
try:
    conn.commit()
except Exception as e:
    # this line works fine:
    # if type( e ) == mysql.connector.errors.DataError:
    # this doesn't:
    if type( e ) in mysql.connector.errors:
        # do some error-handling, logging, etc.
```

To begin with I was happy with the line testing for `e` being an instance of `mysql.connector.errors.DataError`. I process this in a special way, since it is not a "fatal" error in my context.

But another error has just cropped up which is another non-fatal one, also requiring processing in a special way, `mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError`.

I want to capture/filter all errors that are in the "package of classes" `mysql.connector.errors`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if issubclass(e, connector.errors.Error):
    # do error handling for mysql related errors
else:
    # do error handling for other errors
```

Comment: Thanks. Ah, yes, if all errors in the package are indeed subclasses of `mysql.connector.errors.Error`, this would work for my purposes.  But is there no way of just finding whether some class `somepackage.X` is a member of `somepackage`? Of course it just occurs to me that you can analyse the fully qualified name of class X here (i.e. string analysis) ... but that is surely too clunky for Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `isinstance()` wherever the error is an instance of the said class.

For example

```
try:
   conn.commit()
except Exception as e:
   if isinstance(e, mysql.connector.errors.ErrorName):
      #do something
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow!  I think you may have slightly misunderstood the question: I'm not asking whether a variable is an instance of a class, but whether a class is a member of a given package.

Comment: Thanks. Anyways an error is an instance of class, so you can verify if a specific error is an instance of a specific exception. For more general exception handling you can use the issubclass method write in the other answer